# Find $|z|$ and $\arg (z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

$z$ is a complex number defined by

$$z=(2\cos\theta-\sec\theta)\left(1+e^{i2\theta}\right)$$
for $-\frac\pi4<\theta<\frac\pi4$

Find $|z|$ and $\arg (z)$.

Thks

Comment: Hint: use $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$. For $\operatorname{arg}(z)$, note that the cos and sec factor is real. So arg$(z)=$arg$(1+e^{i2\theta})$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: The $(2\cos \theta - \sec \theta)$ is real.

Hint 2: Expand the $e^{i 2 \theta}$ (Euler's formula)